# thread issue creating own winit event thread

Tags: rust, thread-safety

I'm using [winit](https://docs.rs/winit/latest/winit/index.html) to create an app, and I want my own main loop, not the one that winit seems to enforce (I may not have a window in my app, so I can't rely on a winit loop).

My first intuition was to spawn a thread and run the winit loop in it, then use a channel to send all winit events, and in my main loop, check those events with the receiver.

This is what it look like :

```rust
let event_loop = EventLoopBuilder::<MyEventEnum>::with_user_event().build();
let window = WindowBuilder::new().build(&event_loop).unwrap();

let (sender, receiver) = channel::<Event<'static, MyEventEnum>>();

thread::spawn(move || event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
    // ControlFlow::Poll continuously runs the event loop, even if the OS hasn't
    // dispatched any events. This is ideal for games and similar applications.
    control_flow.set_poll();

    sender.send(event.clone());
}));
```

but this throws the error :

```
*mut ()` cannot be sent between threads safely
within `[closure@src\window.rs:22:23: 22:30]`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut ()
```

As I'm fairly new to async, and threads, I don't quite understand what happens here. I'm guessing that the thread can take ownership of the event_loop, and even if the thread either panics or keeps going when I lost the receiver, the fact that I communicate through the channel is safe enough ?

What is going on ? could such a thing be possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must *create* the event loop in the same thread you `run()` it. This is [specifically required by `winit`](https://docs.rs/winit/latest/winit/event_loop/struct.EventLoop.html):

> Note that this cannot be shared across threads (due to platform-dependant logic forbidding it), as such it is neither `Send` nor `Sync`. If you need cross-thread access, the `Window` created from this can be sent to an other thread, and the `EventLoopProxy` allows you to wake up an `EventLoop` from another thread.

You can have the thread send the `Window` and/or `EventLoopProxy` to another thread on a channel, instead.

```rust
thread::spawn(move || {
    let event_loop = EventLoopBuilder::<MyEventEnum>::with_user_event().build();
    let window = WindowBuilder::new().build(&event_loop).unwrap();

    some_channel.send(window);

    event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
        ...
    })
});
```

You will also find that you can't send the `Event`s either, for a different lifetime — their lifetime is not `'static`. Instead of sending `winit`'s events, you will have to translate them into your own event type. It's also generally not a good idea anyway to process all events asynchronously — it can lead to the user interface acting in peculiar ways. Instead, you should handle individual events on the event loop thread for clicking and drawing and so on, and then send more *high level* events ("start this operation" sort of things) to the rest of your application on its other thread.